# How can I show hidden HtmlTable "columns" via JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have HtmlTable rows like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="centertextnowrap"><strong>Description of Expense</strong></td>
    <td class="centertext"><label>Date 1: </label><input type="date" id="date1" name="date1"/></td>
    <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 2: </label><input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"/></td>
    <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 3: </label><input type="date" id="date3" name="date3"/></td>
    <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 4: </label><input type="date" id="date4" name="date4"/></td>
    <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 5: </label><input type="date" id="date5" name="date5"/></td>
    <td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 6: </label><input type="date" id="date6" name="date6"/></td>
    <td class="skybluebackground centertext"><label><strong>Total Expenses</strong></label></td>
    <td colspan="4" class="nobordercell centertext"><label>Comments</label></td>
</tr>
```

I have six "columns" of cells for Date1, Date2, ... Date6

I want to start off showing just Date1, and then make the other Date columns visible as/if necessary.

So, I created a "hide" class:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

...that is applied to all of the date columns except Date1 like so, as shown above:

```
<td class="centertext hide"><label>Date 2: </label><input type="date" id="date2" name="date2"/></td>
```

This works fine for hiding that entire column (provided I decorate the appropriate td in each row with the "hide" class, of course). I plan on then making the columns visible when needed via this jQuery:

```
if // add a second date column {
    $("#date2").removeClass("hide");
    $("#airfare2").removeClass("hide");
    . . .
    $("#totals2").removeClass("hide");
}
```

In response to an "Add Another Date" button click, I can keep track of which is the next column to "unveil". This seems plausible, yet perhaps a little tedious.

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `.hasClass()` and `.next()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:first` selector with the `hide` class. Like following

```
    $("td.hide:first").removeClass("hide");
```

An example

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("td.hide:first").removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td class="hide">Column 2</td>
    <td class="hide">Column 3</td>
    <td class="hide">Column 4</td>
    <td class="hide">Column 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Show More</button>
```

Comment: Okay, I'm going to use this; in the meantime, though, I have another pressing question that will have my old code (not the source of the current issue).

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work, as with each selection of the "Add another date" I need to unhide several cells (tds), not just one.

Comment: If you update your question or post a new one with details about which `td`s you want to unhide we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector. For example, if you wanted to show the "Date 5" column, you could write:

```
$("#tableId td:nth-child(6)").removeClass("hide")
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ya6fbd8s/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable at the beginning:

```
 var date = 1;
```

And your 'add another date' button should do something like this.

```
date = (date + 1);
$( '<td class="centertext hide"><label>Date: </label><input type="date" id="date"'+date' name="date"'+date'/></td>" ).appendTo( "tr" )';
```